# SVG - Fill the hole (Transparent part) of a path

Tags: svg

I have a path which creates a border shape for a letter P, in other words, the hole of a path is the letter P. I use transparent background for the overall element (Here I only included one part of it).

I am curious if I can somehow modify the background for that specific path only, so the result would be having a colored letter P - (Red for example).

I tried using `fill-rule`, which by definition would give me what I need, but it didn't work out.

> The fill-rule attribute is a presentation attribute defining the
>   algorithm to use to determine the inside part of a shape.

```html
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="700 600 600 700" enable-background="new 0 0 2000 2000" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <path fill="#1E1F4E" d="M845.19,914.329H691.147c-4.745,0-8.592,3.847-8.592,8.592v154.041c0,4.747,3.847,8.593,8.592,8.593H845.19
      c4.745,0,8.591-3.846,8.591-8.593V922.921C853.781,918.176,849.935,914.329,845.19,914.329z M802.316,996.693
      c-7.187,6.827-17.346,10.241-30.474,10.241c-3.215,0-6.694-0.23-10.436-0.689c-3.741-0.46-7.745-1.149-12.011-2.068v38.89
      c0,8.403,0.917,13.622,2.756,15.654c2.494,2.89,6.268,4.331,11.323,4.331h5.12v3.645h-57.204v-3.645h5.021
      c5.646,0,9.682-1.834,12.111-5.512c1.312-2.033,1.968-6.859,1.968-14.474v-86.249c0-8.401-0.885-13.618-2.657-15.654
      c-2.56-2.886-6.367-4.331-11.422-4.331h-5.021v-3.643h48.933c11.946,0,21.366,1.23,28.257,3.693
      c6.893,2.46,12.701,6.613,17.427,12.453c4.726,5.843,7.09,12.768,7.09,20.775C813.098,981.005,809.503,989.866,802.316,996.693z"/>
     <path fill="#1E1F4E" d="M777.062,944.856c-4.332-2.462-9.255-3.693-14.768-3.693c-3.347,0-7.648,0.626-12.898,1.871v55.53
      c3.478,0.656,6.562,1.149,9.255,1.478c2.689,0.328,4.986,0.493,6.892,0.493c6.825,0,12.715-2.643,17.673-7.927
      c4.955-5.283,7.433-12.125,7.433-20.528c0-5.776-1.182-11.141-3.545-16.098C784.741,951.026,781.395,947.317,777.062,944.856z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed the fill attribute and I use css to set the fill for the g group. I've changed the viewBox attribute to the size of the group. Now you change the fill of the group when you hover the svg element. Please let me know if you need the svg element to be that big as your's is. In this case you may need to add a rect behind the P.

```css
g{fill:#1E1F4E;}
svg:hover g{fill:red;}
```

```html
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="100" viewBox="682.55 914.33 171.22 171.22">
    <g>
     <path  d="M845.19,914.329H691.147c-4.745,0-8.592,3.847-8.592,8.592v154.041c0,4.747,3.847,8.593,8.592,8.593H845.19
      c4.745,0,8.591-3.846,8.591-8.593V922.921C853.781,918.176,849.935,914.329,845.19,914.329z M802.316,996.693
      c-7.187,6.827-17.346,10.241-30.474,10.241c-3.215,0-6.694-0.23-10.436-0.689c-3.741-0.46-7.745-1.149-12.011-2.068v38.89
      c0,8.403,0.917,13.622,2.756,15.654c2.494,2.89,6.268,4.331,11.323,4.331h5.12v3.645h-57.204v-3.645h5.021
      c5.646,0,9.682-1.834,12.111-5.512c1.312-2.033,1.968-6.859,1.968-14.474v-86.249c0-8.401-0.885-13.618-2.657-15.654
      c-2.56-2.886-6.367-4.331-11.422-4.331h-5.021v-3.643h48.933c11.946,0,21.366,1.23,28.257,3.693
      c6.893,2.46,12.701,6.613,17.427,12.453c4.726,5.843,7.09,12.768,7.09,20.775C813.098,981.005,809.503,989.866,802.316,996.693z"/>
     <path  d="M777.062,944.856c-4.332-2.462-9.255-3.693-14.768-3.693c-3.347,0-7.648,0.626-12.898,1.871v55.53
      c3.478,0.656,6.562,1.149,9.255,1.478c2.689,0.328,4.986,0.493,6.892,0.493c6.825,0,12.715-2.643,17.673-7.927
      c4.955-5.283,7.433-12.125,7.433-20.528c0-5.776-1.182-11.141-3.545-16.098C784.741,951.026,781.395,947.317,777.062,944.856z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

the OP is commenting:

> I was talking about the coloring the letter P, not the border.

In this case I've changed the path so that you have the letter as a path

```css
g{fill:#fff;}
svg:hover g{fill:red;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="100" viewBox="682.55 914.33 171.22 171.22">
      
      <path fill="#1E1F4E"  d="M845.19,914.329H691.147c-4.745,0-8.592,3.847-8.592,8.592v154.041c0,4.747,3.847,8.593,8.592,8.593H845.19
      c4.745,0,8.591-3.846,8.591-8.593V922.921C853.781,918.176,849.935,914.329,845.19,914.329z" />
<g>
     <path  d="M802.316,996.693
      c-7.187,6.827-17.346,10.241-30.474,10.241c-3.215,0-6.694-0.23-10.436-0.689c-3.741-0.46-7.745-1.149-12.011-2.068v38.89
      c0,8.403,0.917,13.622,2.756,15.654c2.494,2.89,6.268,4.331,11.323,4.331h5.12v3.645h-57.204v-3.645h5.021
      c5.646,0,9.682-1.834,12.111-5.512c1.312-2.033,1.968-6.859,1.968-14.474v-86.249c0-8.401-0.885-13.618-2.657-15.654
      c-2.56-2.886-6.367-4.331-11.422-4.331h-5.021v-3.643h48.933c11.946,0,21.366,1.23,28.257,3.693
      c6.893,2.46,12.701,6.613,17.427,12.453c4.726,5.843,7.09,12.768,7.09,20.775C813.098,981.005,809.503,989.866,802.316,996.693z
                M777.062,944.856c-4.332-2.462-9.255-3.693-14.768-3.693c-3.347,0-7.648,0.626-12.898,1.871v55.53
      c3.478,0.656,6.562,1.149,9.255,1.478c2.689,0.328,4.986,0.493,6.892,0.493c6.825,0,12.715-2.643,17.673-7.927
      c4.955-5.283,7.433-12.125,7.433-20.528c0-5.776-1.182-11.141-3.545-16.098C784.741,951.026,781.395,947.317,777.062,944.856z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: "so the result would be having a colored letter P - (Red for example)." I was talking about the coloring the letter P, not the border. But thanks anyway. I ended up adding a white rectangle over it.